# template0 default encoding in Postgresql 8.4

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have created a Database with following command in PostgreSQL 8.4.
"CREATE DATABASE dbname TEMPLATE template0"
My Question is what is the encoding scheme of the default template that is template0.
For me when I create the database it shows me encoding as UTF-8,will template0 be system dependent or UTF-8 would be the default encoding.

Answer (score 3):

It is system dependent and depends on your system encoding or what you specified when the database cluster was created with `initdb`. You can specify it with the --encoding flag.

Comment: Seems a very simple question but how to get what encoding is there in my Windows System.

Comment: Sorry, don't really know about Windows. It might be that it's always UTF-8.